# find exec does not work with command aliases?

Tags: find, alias, macos

I'm trying to do a `find` with a `-exec` of a command aliased in my `.bash_profile` on macOS. The `find` command shows

```
find: [alias cmd]: No such file or directory
```

when I use

```
find ./ -iname *.doc -exec sha256 {} \;`
```

where `alias sha256="shasum -a 256"`.

Running the unaliased command works correctly.

Is `find` not supposed to be able to access defined command aliases, or is this a bug in `find`?

Answer (score 4):

The `-exec` option of `find` wants pure executables, while `alias`-es are a shell feature, meaning that they exist only when you are within a shell.

You can run any command within a shell by making `-exec` run `bash -c command`. However, for aliases to be accepted, the shell has to be run interactively.

You can trick the interactiveness by executing `bash -ic sha256`, but since you put your alias definition in `.bash_profile` you would also need to trick it as a “login shell” as well as an interactive one, because that file is only read by so-called “login shells”. That is, you should execute `bash -lic sha256`. But that is slower and pollutes your sessions log a bit.

Therefore I would advise you to rather put your alias definition in `.bashrc` file (just create it if don't have it yet), so that your alias can be used by a simpler `bash -i` instead of `bash -li`.

This would make your whole command like:

```
find ./ -iname *.doc -exec bash -ic 'sha256 "$1"' -- {} \;
```

If you really must keep your alias definition in `.bash_profile` then make your command like:

```
find ./ -iname *.doc -exec bash -lic 'sha256 "$1"' -- {} \;
```

Answer (score 2):

No, your alias is derived from bash. `find` expects an executable in your `PATH` environment variable. (if you type `which <cmd | alias>` and get nothing, find will complain)